# Drupal SMTP is not working

Tags: 7, emails

I am using STMP module for D7.

When i put test email abc@gmail.com, i have received the email but

When i check show original i am getting received from

```
Received: from usernem by myhost username with local (Exim 4.85)
```

Why it is so ?

Also i have enter wrong password and tried to send an email. i recieved the email

Seems SMTP is not working on my site

Below are my settings

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change and check

```
SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP port: 587
Use Encrypted Protocol : Use TLS

Username: Your Email Id
Password: Your Password
```

For default email settings check

> /admin/config/system/mailsystem

Comment: Now, it is giving me error 

SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.